# Mirror for pear.phing.info

Tags: php, pear, phing

pear.phing.info seems to be down, does anyone know if there are any mirrors available for this package?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: if not, is there a way to install this from their svn repo which I have found a mirror for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are moving servers which may explain the problem. If you an wait a day or two they should be back up.

here is the announcement

http://phing.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1079&dsMessageId=2598123

you may also be able to find an answer re installing from svn.

If I am nort mistaken you can do a pear install from a tarball which is availbale here:

http://phing.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=10094&expandFolder=10094&folderID=0

You can download the tarball and try:

"pear install "

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to download the tarball. This should work just fine:

```
pear install http://phing.tigris.org/files/documents/995/44529/phing-2.3.3.tar.gz
```